# Hive Case Statement

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table A with n columns. Column c1 has tickets in the following pattern:

```
c1

79213
86420
94237
94237-H
65874
32650
26198
26198-H
52041
49567
49567-H
.....
.....
```

Tickets 94237-H, 26198-H, 49567-H are called helper tickets and their parents are 94237, 26198, 49567 resp. Can someone help to write a hive query to generate another table B with all the columns in table A removing the helper tickets 'H' in column c1 plus adding one more column ch with the following results: In column ch, the parent tickets should be labeled 1 and the rest of the tickets should be labeled 0.

```
c1        ch 

79213     0
86420     0
94237     1
65874     0
32650     0
26198     1
52041     0
49567     1
.....
.....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

First split the information in the `key` and in teh `helper flag`

```
select 
  replace(c1,'-H') c1,
  case when c1 like '%-H' then 1 end as is_helper
from t1
```

Than simple get all key (`GROUP BY c1`) and use `MAX` the check if a helper exists to the key.

```
with t2 as (
select 
  replace(c1,'-H') c1,
  case when c1 like '%-H' then 1 end as is_helper
from t1)
select c1, max(is_helper) ch
from t2
group by c1;
```

gives

```
C1              CH
------- ----------
86420              
65874              
32650              
26198            1 
79213              
94237            1 
52041              
49567            1
```

Note, I have no hive, so in problems reformulte or use othe standard functions.

Example:

```
select 
  replace(c1,'-H') c1,
  max(case when c1 like '%-H' then 1 end) as ch
from t1
group by replace(c1,'-H')
```